# Is there a better method of dependency function calls versus stacking them?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, function, express, dependencies

I'm in Express router code, rendering with Jade and pulling data from MongoDB to prep for that.  Is there a better method of pulling together all the data required versus the following construct?  Note that there isn't a dependency among tables restaurants, customers and drivers requiring that one return first--I just need all three to execute before the page render.

Some of these cascaded calls are getting pretty deep in some cases.  There has to be a better construct, right?

```
router.get('/iframe_map/:restaurantid/:customerid', function(req, res, next) {
  Restaurant.findOne({'_id': req.params.restaurantid}, '-_id address name phone status lat lng LatLng marker', function(restaurantErr, restaurantDoc) {
    Customer.findOne({'_id': req.params.customerid}, '-_id address name phone status lat lng LatLng marker', function(customerErr, customerDoc) {
      Driver.find({}, '-_id letterOrdinal address firstName lastName phone status lat lng LatLng marker', {sort: {letterOrdinal: 1}}, function(driverErr, driverDocs) {
        res.render('iframe_map', {
          title:              "Google Map",
          defaultZoomLevel:   12,
          defaultCityState:   ", San Diego, CA",
          oRestaurant:        restaurantDoc,
          oCustomer:          customerDoc,
          oDrivers:           driverDocs
        });  // End of res.render()
      });    // End of Driver.find()
    });      // End of Customer.find()
  });        // End of Restaurant.find()
});          // End of router.get()
```

Comment: you can use Async Waterfall https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall

Comment: @Michelem Hm... *IF* my DB functions had dependencies among themselves then I'd agree.  (Not a bad attempt, though.)  Since my DB functions don't have dependencies among themselves I'm thinking that async.parallel may be more appropriate here.  https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback  (Thanks.)

Comment: Yes of course Waterfall is only an example, the Async module it's what you should try (and if parallel suites better for you then use that)

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code rewritten with Async Waterfall:

```
router.get('/iframe_map/:restaurantid/:customerid', function(req, res, next) {
    var obj = {};
    async.waterfall([
        function(done) {
            Restaurant.findOne({'_id': req.params.restaurantid}, '-_id address name phone status lat lng LatLng marker', function(err, items) {
                if (err) done(err);
                obj.restaurant = items;
                done(null, obj);
            });
        },
        function(obj, done) {
            Customer.findOne({'_id': req.params.customerid}, '-_id address name phone status lat lng LatLng marker', function(err, items) {
                if (err) done(err);
                obj.customer = items;
                done(null, obj);
            });
        },
        function(obj, done) {
            Driver.find({}, '-_id letterOrdinal address firstName lastName phone status lat lng LatLng marker', {sort: {letterOrdinal: 1}}, function(err, items) {
                if (err) done(err);
                obj.driver = items;
                done(null, obj);
            });
        }
    ], function (err, result) {
        res.render('iframe_map', {
          title:              "Google Map",
          defaultZoomLevel:   12,
          defaultCityState:   ", San Diego, CA",
          oRestaurant:        result.restaurant,
          oCustomer:          result.customer,
          oDrivers:           result.driver
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I'm surprised you were able to put it together so fast.  As I mention above, there's no inter-DB dependencies so the call-chain seems a bit unnecessary, especially given the parameter confusion this introduces.  Here, we have several "obj" variables which each represent different types of objects.  Likewise, we have more than one "done" callback function reference.  The original code was 16 lines long and it's now twice the length at 33 lines of code.  (Granted, the original code ran wide.)  I'm going to look into async.parallel though.  Again, thanks.

Comment: oh well I think it's always better to have code easy to be read (by you but also and mainly by others) than having it "short" so I think this is a good approach instead using the "callback hell" when you need to do something like this. That said, as you told, I wrote it really fast, you could refine it, for example you can pass every arguments you want to the done callback instead putting everything into a single object. You are welcome.